# 18.04 LTS upgrade has stopped WOL (wake-on-LAN)

Tags: networking, 18.04, wakeonlan

I have upgraded to 18.04 LTS 64-bit from 16.04 this week, prompted by the software updater. Under 16.04 wol worked without problems. Not now, searching for solutions  I have installed ethtool and can see the network settings. My eth0 has become enp1s0 and ethtool clearly shows 'Wake-on: d' which seems to mean No, and I can run 'sudo ethtool -s enp1s0 wol g' which changes the status to g which seems to mean Yes. My PC wakes correctly but Wake-on is set back to d. How to I change it permanently to g. I have searched on this and the solutions I am finding are years old and do not work anymore. Has anyone got an 18.04 solution.

Ask Ubuntu seems to think this is a duplicate query to 'Wake-on-LAN quit working with latest kernel (Bionic)' which is about booting from different Kernels and confuses the hell out of me. My question is just a procedural question about setting wol to always be on. I have an answer, it works and I think people who just need it to work will find this more useful

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you create a new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Add three lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
ethtool -s enp1s0 wol g
exit 0
```

Save and close the text editor. Now do:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

You should be all set.

Comment: It seems obvious, but it doesn't work on my Ubuntu 23.10.